Question about different hypothesis of Poisson Summation Formula
I've studied two different proofs of the Poisson Summation Formula under two different sets of hypotheses.
The first one is the following:

Theorem 1: Let $f$ be an $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function and suppose that there exists two constants $C>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $$\vert f(x) \vert \leq \frac{C}{(1+ \vert x \vert) ^{n+\delta}} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \vert \widehat{f}(x) \vert \leq \frac{C}{(1+ \vert x \vert) ^{n+\delta}} \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n. \ \ \ (1) $$
Then $f$ is a.e. equal to continuous function and (up to changing $f$ on a set of measure zero) we have that $$\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n} f(x+m) = \sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n} \widehat{f}(m) e^{2 \pi i m \cdot x} \  \forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n$$

The second one is the Following:

Theorem 2: Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a $BV(\mathbb{R})$ and normalized function. Then the sum $\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} f(x+m)$ is absolutely convergent everywhere and: $$\lim\limits_{N\to +\infty} \sum\limits_{m=-N}^N f(x+m) = \lim\limits_{N\to +\infty} \sum\limits_{k=-N}^N \widehat{f}(k) e^{2 \pi i x \cdot k} \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

My question is the following: When introducing Theorem 2, the professor said that it generalizes the case $n = 1$ of Theorem 1. Which means that:

Claim: if $f$ is an $ L^1(\mathbb{R}) $ continuous function  satisfying $(1)$, i.e. hypotheses of Theorem 1, then $ f \in BV(\mathbb{R}) $.

I understand that the inequality involving the Fourier transform might control the oscillation of $ f $, and hence the total variation of $ f $ in some sense, but I am unable to prove it. Can someone help me in proving or disproving the Claim?
